# AVR SPI target with interrupt

Tags: avr, spi, atmega, interrupts

For a project, I want to have two microcontrollers talk to each other via an SPI interface. I wrote the following code for the target microcontroller:

```
volatile uint8_t data;

void spi_init_slave (void)
{
 DDRB=(1<<PINB4);               //MISO as OUTPUT
 SPCR=(1<<SPE)|(1<<SPIE);       //Enable SPI && interrupt enable bit
 SPDR=0;
}

uint8_t SPI_SlaveReceive(void)
{      
  /* Wait for reception complete */
  while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))   ;
  /* Return data register */
  return    SPDR;
}

ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{
  uint8_t y = SPI_SlaveReceive();
  PORTD = y;
}

int main(void)
{
    DDRD = (1<<PIND0) | (1<<PIND1) | (1<<PIND2) | (1<<PIND3) | (1<<PIND4);
    spi_init_slave();                             //Initialize slave SPI

    sei();
    while(1)
    {

    }
}
```

The master is sending a number which the target displays using the LEDs attached to port D.

I'm using an Atmega8P for this project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most apparent problem I can see is the following line:

```
SPCR=(1<<SPE)|(1<SPIE);
```

Is missing a less than sign and should include `(1<<SPIE)` to enable the SPI interrupt. Note that the current expression `(1<SPIE)` will be equivalent to the boolean expression `(1 < 7)` which will result in a value of 1. So that also means at the moment you'll be setting `SPR0` for a speed of fosc/16 on the master.

Comment: You've made my day. Thanks! Only the slave doesn't have to "match" the speed of the master. Quoted atmel datasheep pp 126: "Bits 1, 0 – SPR1, SPR0: SPI Clock Rate Select 1 and 0. These two bits control the SCK rate of the dev
ice configured as a Master. SPR1 and SPR0 have
no effect on the Slave."

Comment: Ahh yes good point of course I re-worded that part.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a year old, but I thought I would just point out that when I tried implementing your code, the interrupt routine was only firing every other SPI transfer.

I believe this is because of this line:

```
while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))   ;
```

when you actually want:

```
while ((SPSR & (1<<SPIF)))   ;
```

Hopefully that saves someone else some of the time I spent scratching my head.

Comment: Actually when the interrupt is fired the SPIF flag will always get cleared. So the while loop can be removed entirely, it is never executed. The interrupt is fired when transfer is completed, for both slave and master.

Answer (score 2):

I used also your source code. My slave got only every 2 message.
The cause was this line in the `SPI_SlaveReceive` function:

```
while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
```

This is only important when you use SPI by polling. If you want to use SPI communication controlled by interrupts - slave side, delete this line.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never right ?
Just had the same problem myself, and none of the answers above is correct execpt the one above me.

The function "uint8_t SPI_SlaveReceive(void)" is meant to be used in main. 
to have it interrupt driven you just need to read the SPDR directly in your isr.

ISR(SPI_STC_vect)
{
  uint8_t y = SPDR;
  PORTD = y;
}